# Trying to share data across views Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to share the username across my fixed blade which I am extending in other views. I am using the controller to verify my users and thereby passing the data to the views. However, I get an error saying

```
Undefined variable: username (View: 
E:\LaravelProjects\adminLTE\resources\views\layout\fixed.blade.php)
```

I have clearly passed the data using the View:share in my controller. What could be my possible error?

My code is as follows:

**controller.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use session;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Auth;
use View;
use Hash;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input; 
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class mainController extends Controller
{   
    //user login
    public function login(){
        return view('login');
    } 

    public function logs_in(Request $request){ 
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        $hashedPassword = User::where('email', $email)->first();


        $role_type = User::select('role_type')->where('email', $email)->get();
        $username = User::select('name')->where('email', $email)->get();

            if(Hash::check($password, $hashedPassword->password)){ 
                if($role_type == '[{"role_type":"Administrator"}]'){ 
                    $request->session()->put('admin_name', $username );
                    View::share('username', $email);
                    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
                } else if ($role_type == '[{"role_type":"Staff"}]') {
                    $request->session()->put('success');
                    return redirect()->route('staff');
                } else if ($role_type == '[{"role_type":"User"}]') {
                    $request->session()->put('success');
                    return redirect()->route('user_dashboard');
                };
            } else {
                return redirect()->route('login')->with('login_error', 'Invalid 
                credentials entered');
            };
    }
```

**fixed.blade.php** I am getting the error from this view

```
 <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <img src="{{ asset ('images/logo.png')}}" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
      <span class="hidden-xs"><i>{{ $username }}</i></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <!-- User image -->
      <li class="user-panel">
        <p align="center">
          <img src="{{ asset ('images/logo.png')}}" style="width:100px;height:100px;" alt="User Image" >
          <h4 align="center">{{ $username }}</h4>
        </p>
      </li>
```

Comment: Why are you not using attempt method of laravel for login?

Comment: See the Laravel docs on [Sharing Data With All Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#sharing-data-with-all-views). Or use view composers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Your `AppServiceProvider`

```
public function boot()
{
    View::share('username', request()->input('email'));
}
```

Now this value will be shared across all the views and you can access

```
{{ $username }}
```

if you want to access logged in user data you can use

```
@if(auth()->check())
  {{ auth()->user()->email }}
@endif
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Okay this works, but it does not display any value on the {{ $username }} label

Comment: @JayPatel  try request()->input('email') ...I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you use `attempt` method of laravel for login as specified [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authenticating-users), you can access username and other fields of the user that is logged in anywhere without the need to share the variables accross views.

```
{{ auth()->user()->username }}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

> you should place calls to share within a service provider's boot method. You are free to add them to the AppServiceProvider or generate a separate service provider to house them:

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
   public function boot()
   {
       View::share('key', 'value'); //Do the sharing here
   }

/**
 * Register the service provider.
 *
 * @return void
 */
   public function register()
   {
      //
   }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to pass my data to the provider in this case. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: @JayPatel Are you trying to share data of "authenticated user" ?

Comment: Yes I am trying to share data of the authenticated user

Comment: @JayPatel then just use for example  `{{\Auth::user()->role->name}}` in blade